# How to DROP icmp requests with firewalld?

Tags: rhel, firewall, ping, firewalld, icmp

How to DROP icmp requests with firewalld?

An equivalent example instead using *iptables* would be:

```
$ iptables -A INPUT --protocol icmp --in-interface enp0s8 -j DROP
```

The above produces the desired result (no response) like so:

```
[root@lexy1 ~]# ping l2
PING lexy2.example.vm (192.168.57.102) 56(84) bytes of data.
                              ︙
                      (no other output)
                              ︙
```

I'm able to block icmp requests with firewalld using something like:

```
$ firewall-cmd --zone=internal --add-icmp-block={echo-request,echo-reply}
```

However *ping* returns output like so:

```
[root@lexy1 ~]# ping l2
PING lexy2.example.vm (192.168.57.102) 56(84) bytes of data.
From lexy2.example.vm (192.168.57.102) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Prohibited
From lexy2.example.vm (192.168.57.102) icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Prohibited
From lexy2.example.vm (192.168.57.102) icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Prohibited
                              ︙
```

Ping should receive no indication that a server exists at this address.
(This is not an attempt at security through obscurity.)

Comment: It seems to me that you have to create a new zone whose policy is DROP, then you can set icmp-block-inversion; then ICMP traffic matching that zone will be dropped. [reference](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/sec-Using_Firewalls.html#sec-Configuring_firewalld), quoting: "To enable inverting the ICMP Filter, click the Invert Filter check box on the right. Only marked ICMP types are now accepted, all other are rejected. In a zone using the DROP target, they are dropped."

Comment: Thanks @JeffSchaller, that works.  I just moved the interface to the predefined `drop` zone, added the services I need on that interface, and ran `$ firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=drop --add-icmp-block-inversion`.  If you answer, I will accept.

Comment: A slightly quicker way might be to just change the target of the current zone to `DROP`, assuming there's only the one desired interface in the current zone.  Like this:  `$ firewall-cmd --permanent [--zone=zone] --set-target=DROP`.  As all services would already have been configured for the current zone you'd just need to add the 'icmp block inversion'.

Answer (score 3):

Following should work

#### drop all ICMP

```
firewall-cmd --set-target=DROP --zone=public --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=nagios --remove-icmp-block={echo-request,echo-reply,timestamp-request,timestamp-reply} --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

#### revert to default

```
firewall-cmd --set-target=default --zone=public --permanent  
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with the command below:

```
systemctl stop iptables
```

Comment: Please use proper syntax for commands & explain what your solution (the command you posted here) should *case*